# Bases for a subspace versus basis for the ambient vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $U \subset V$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$. Prove or disprove each of the following assertions.
>
> (a) Any basis of $U$ is contained in a basis of $V$.
>
> (b) Any basis of $V$ contains a basis of $U$.

Here is my attempt.

Part (a) is true: any basis of $U$ can be extended, by induction, to a basis for $V$. (If the vector spaces are infinite-dimensional, I can't use induction, but I believe the result is still true.)

Part (b) is not true. Let $V = \mathbb{R}^2$. Then $\left\{(1,0), (0,1) \right\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $U = \mathrm{span}(1,1)$, then this basis for $V$ fails to contain a basis for $U$.

How does this look? I'm concerned about the case where $U$ and $V$ may be infinite-dimensional. Can I extend $U$ to a basis for $V$ by using the Axiom of Choice? I'm not exactly sure how that works since there's no guarantee that the algorithm for finding the basis terminates, unlike in the finite-dimensional case by induction.

Comment: "By induction" only works in the finite dimensional case. But the standard proof that any vector space (infinite dimensional or not) has a basis can be extended to prove that if $V$ is a vector space, $\delta$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$, and $\gamma$ is a spanning set of $V$ such that $\delta\subseteq \gamma$, then there exists a basis $\beta$ for $V$ such that $\delta\subseteq\beta\subseteq\gamma$. In particular every linearly independent subset can be extendeed to a basis. It's **not** algorithmic, as the existence of a basis is equvalent to the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: I think Theorem 1.9 in the following link (which is the theorem Arturo Magidin has explained) is exactly what you are looking for: https://tinyurl.com/238ktzhr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part (b) is perfect. The way you phrase Part (a) only works for finite dimensional spaces, as you note.

That every vector space has a basis is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice; in fact it is easier to prove the equivalence of "Every spanning set of a vector space contains a basis" (which is a stronger statement) to the Axiom of Choice. That means that in general there is no "algorithm" to produce a basis for an infinite dimensional vector space (though one may be able to do so for *specific* vector spaces).

What you want is the following theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $V$ be a vector space. Then every linearly independent subset of $V$ can be extended to a basis.

This is in turn a consequence of the following more general result:

**Theorem.** Let $V$ be a vector space. If $A$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$, $S$ is a spanning set of $V$, and $A\subseteq S$, then there exists a $\beta$, $A\subseteq \beta\subseteq S$ such that $\beta$ is a basis for $V$.

The result you want follows by taking $S=V$.

The proof uses Zorn's Lemma. Consider the set
$$\mathscr{S}=\{X\subseteq V\mid A\subseteq X\subseteq S\text{ and }X\text{ is linearly independent}\}$$
partially ordered by set inclusion. It is straighforward to prove that any $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathscr{S}$ is bounded above, either by $X$ itself if $\mathcal{C}$ is empty, and by $\cup\mathcal{C}$ if $\mathcal{C}$ is nonempty. By Zorn's Lemma, $\mathscr{S}$ has maximal elements. Let $\beta$ be such an element, and prove that $\beta$ must span $V$ (otherwise, there is some $x\in S$ that is not in $\mathrm{span}(\beta)$, and then $\beta\cup\{x\}$ would contradict maximality). Thus, $\beta$ is a basis for $V$ with the desired properties.

You can now invoke the theorem to show that any basis for a subspace $U$ can be extended to a basis for $V$ (assuming the Axiom of Choice, whch you need anyway to ensure that both $U$ and $V$ have bases in the first place in the arbitrary setting).